# Reading RFID through USB and using it on a local server

Tags: linux, usb, rfid

I have a [Phidget RFID](http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?product_id=1023) reader that will be connected to a Linux (Ubuntu) computer. I would like to get the data from the RFID/USB to be usable in a web browser (on a local server). Can anyone recommend a stable and simple way to do this? My knowledge about Linux is beginner and Python is none. I have been trying to use Python to read and send the RFID code to a browser, but did not succeed. Also I have the feeling that on Linux there should be a smarter way to get the RFID code to be used with Javascript and PHP by reading the USB directly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it by saving the RFID tag to a .txt file which I can read with PHP or Javascript on my local server. For anyone having the same question, check http://fablab.waag.org/project/alzheimer-open-source-radio/documentation/5894